# Guzzle, JSON and UTF-16

Tags: json, guzzle, utf-16

We're using Guzzle 6 making a request to a .NET API from our Laravel 5 application.

e.g (not real code)

```
$response = Guzzle\Client->get('/utf16-endpoint');
$array = json_decode($response->getBody());
```

This turns `$array = null` and again with any other variations like

```
$array = json_decode((string) $response->getBody());
```

or

```
$array = json_decode($response->getBody()->getContent());
```

These all end up returning null

I cant paste the API response because it keeps getting converted by things like Gists, Pastebin etc, so I've uploaded a response as a .txt file http://consolewatch.io/response.txt which if you open in sublime/atom etc - it should show as "UTF-16 LE"

What would be the correct way (we're using PHP7) to take this response from guzzle and make sure the JSON is converted into an array with objects within it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can notice from the docs, that [json_decode() works only with UTF-8 in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

So you just have to convert you response to UTF-8 and it will work:

```
$content = $response->getBody()->getContent();
$data = json_decode(
    mb_convert_encoding($content, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-16LE')
);
```

Comment: The key I noticed was spotting that UTF-16 is NOT UTF-16LE! Didn't notice we needed the LE, once we added that all was fine!